# jquery autocomplete with codeigniter - passing controller name to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter autocomplete working correctly. The javascript syntax is:

*controller*

```
  function autocomplete(){
    $this->load->view('sales/new_order_details');
  }
```

*model*

```
function get_customer($q){
    $this->db->select('CustomerName');
    $this->db->like('CustomerName', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('Customers');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['CustomerName'])); //build an array
      }
      $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($row_set));

    }
  }
```

*javascript*

```
$(function(){
  $("#customer").autocomplete({
    source: "get_customers"
  });
});
```

The concept of the MVC framework is reuseability. How can I pass the name of the requesting controller to the javascript so it can be dynamically used by several controller methods?

So something like:

```
var method=controllername.requestingmethod;
$(function(){
  $("#customer").autocomplete({
    source: "method"
  });
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you can pass it as a variable

the controller:

```
function autocomplete(){
    $data['methodName'] = "autocomplete";
    $this->load->view('sales/new_order_details',$data);
}
```

Now you can access it in the view like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#customer").autocomplete({
        source: "<?=$methodName?>"
    });
});
```

Comment: That is awesome and so simple. Thanks Frederik.

Answer (score 0):

If you have written yout jquery or javascript code in php extension file you can do it like this

```
$(function(){
    $("#customer").autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo site_url('controllername/methodname');?>"
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Raheel, think you miss understood my questions - probably my fault. in your example `controllername/methodname` needs to be specified. how do I make that equal to the requesting controller/method so I can call the same javascript from several methods. this way I don't have to create a separate autocomplete.js file for each autocomplete field in my application?

Comment: Secondly, what is php extension file? an external js file and not inline with my page?